# sum the values in a column and add the sum to the filename of a workbook

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

Hello I have been able to create new worksheets based on unique values in a column. In addition to this, i want to sum up the values in a column and include this sum in the filename of each corresponding worksheet.

I want the sum of values in column D to be added to the file name of this workbook in the format Filename_Sum(D).xls

This is what I've done, all i need is to do the sum of Column I2:I, convert the sum to a String and include in the filename (the value in column A)

```
            'Copy/paste the visible data to the new workbook
            My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            With WSNew.Range("A1")
                ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Select                  

            End With

            mySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("I2:I1024"))


            'Save the file in the new folder and close it
            On Error Resume Next
            WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                                cell.Value _
                                & CStr(mySum) & _
                                FileExtStr, FileFormatNum'
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you know nothing about VBA or macros, so here's the shortest amount of steps to do what you're looking for:

Open up your workbook. On your keyboard, hit alt + F11. This will open the VBA developer screen. At the left there is a tree, right click at the top object (VBAProject(YourFileName)) and select Insert > Module. In the module that opened, in the main screen paste this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveWithSum()
Dim SumOfD As Integer
SumOfD = Application.Sum(Range("Sheet1!D:D"))
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\YourFolder\YourFilename" & SumOfD & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

Then hit save. It will prompt to you that your current file format (.xlsx) can run macros. Select no and save your file as YourFile.xlsm.

You're done! The resulting file will be C:\YourFolder\YourFilename##.xlsx.

This script will save all of the renamed files as .xlsx files which CANNOT run the macro again (it will actually disappear from the Developer screen) . If you want to save the files as .xlsm files and let the script continue run in the saved files as well, change the ".xslx" to ".xlsm" and change the FileFormat to 52.

You can create a button on the worksheet that links to the macro (a quick google search will help with that) or just run the macro by selecting View>Macros and run it from there.

Make sure Sheet1! is changed to match your worksheet. Best of luck!

Comment: Hi Nate, thanks for the info. but the macros is designed to pick the file name for each new workbook created from column A of the parent workbook. I am getting "Application-Define or Object-Define error" when i try to run the code

Comment: Why didn't you put that code in the question in the first place?

Comment: Sorry about that Nate. Any ideas how I can achieve the desired?

Comment: Try this. Put in [Option Explicit](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?461140-Classic-VB-What-is-Option-Explicit-and-why-should-I-use-it) at the very, very top of your code and fix all the undeclared variables. That might help you figure it out. I see a bunch of variables in your code above that you might not be aware are actually variables. Also, my code above is close enough to get you what you need. You should be able to massage it into what you need. If you really, really can't do it, explain to me what foldername, FileExtStr, and FileFormatNum are exactly and I'll write it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the Question was posted few years ago I would like to provide an answer for others who search for solution:

```
Sub save_with_value()

Dim Fname As String
Dim cell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False         'replaces existing file if already exists

Fpath = "O:\TEST\Values\"  'folder path - change accordingly to your folder
Fname = »Filename« 
Dim result As Double
result = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("D:D")) 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        Fpath & "\" & Fname & "_" & Format(result, "#,##0.00") & " EUR" & ".xlsx"

End sub
```